# OSX : rmdir "permission denied" but directory removed

Tags: command-line, permissions, osx, directory, rm

I was trying to test the `rmdir` command by removing a `test` directory located in my `Downloads` directory. I have read and write rights on `Downloads`.

I issued `rmdir -p /Users/myself/Downloads/test`
and got `rmdir: /Users/myself/Downloads: Permission denied`
, but the `test` directory was deleted. 
So why do I have this message? Should I care?

I'm using OSX Lion 10.7.3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `man rmdir`:

```
   -p, --parents
          remove DIRECTORY and its ancestors; e.g., `rmdir -p a/b/c' is similar to `rmdir a/b/c a/b a'
```

So your `rmdir` call tries to delete `test` (succeeds), then tries to delete *the parent directory* `Documents` (or rather `Downloads`) and fails... I think.  I'd rather have expected some "directory not empty" error, because why shouldn't you have the permissions to delete this folder?

Comment: Thanks sr_ for your answer. You are right it is "Downloads" not "Documents". Maybe I can't delete "Downloads" because one just can't delete "Downloads" because of a "This folder is required by OS X" thing...

Comment: Possibly, I don't know anything about how OS X alters the general "UNIX-like"-ness encountered everywhere else. :)

Comment: I tried to delete the folder "Sites" via Finder and got that kind of message.